# Radio button changes state on scroll of Sectioned Listview

Tags: android, listview, adapter

I am using the `Sectioned ListView` in my application 
in the row of `ListView` i have `TextView` and `RadioGroup.` 
So when i click the radio button normally it gets clicked and works fine.
      But when i click and scroll the view it the selected view's also get 
vanished and becomes unchecked.

This is the XML i am using

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/relativelay"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/list_bg" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvname"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/check_present"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:onClick="onPresentClick" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/check_absent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/check_present"
            android:onClick="onPresentClick" />
    </RadioGroup>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And this is the adapter i am using for the `Sectioned ListView`....

This is my updated code....

```
public class NamesAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item> {

    private ArrayList<Item> items;
    private LayoutInflater vi;
    private Item objItem;
    private ArrayList<Items> presentSelected = new ArrayList<Items>();;
    private ArrayList<Items> absentSelected = new ArrayList<Items>();;
    private Map<Integer, Boolean> map = new HashMap<Integer, Boolean>();
    ViewHolderSectionName holderSection;
    ViewHolderName holderName;
    Items item;

    public NamesAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Item> items) {
        super(context, 0, items);

        this.items = items;

        vi = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        objItem = items.get(position);

        if (objItem.isSectionItem()) {
            ItemsSections si = (ItemsSections) objItem;

            if (convertView == null
                    || !convertView.getTag().equals(holderSection)) {
                convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.alphabet_separator, null);

                holderSection = new ViewHolderSectionName();
                convertView.setTag(holderSection);
            } else {
                holderSection = (ViewHolderSectionName) convertView.getTag();
            }

            holderSection.section = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.alphabet_letter);

            holderSection.section
                    .setText(String.valueOf(si.getSectionLetter()));

        } else {
            Items ei = (Items) objItem;

            if (convertView == null || !convertView.getTag().equals(holderName)) {
                convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.row, null);

                holderName = new ViewHolderName();

                holderName.name = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.tvname);

                holderName.radioGroup = (RadioGroup) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
                holderName.checkAbsent = (RadioButton) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.check_absent);
                holderName.checkPresent = (RadioButton) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.check_present);

                Boolean present = map.get(position);

                Log.e("Names Adapter", "is Selected " + present);

                if (present != null && present.booleanValue()) {
                    // set present checkbox selected
                    holderName.checkPresent.setSelected(true);
                } else {
                    holderName.checkAbsent.setSelected(true);
                    // set absent checkbox selected
                }

                holderName.radioGroup
                        .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group,
                                    int checkedId) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                switch (checkedId) {
                                case R.id.check_absent:
                                    item = (Items) holderName.checkAbsent
                                            .getTag();
                                    absentSelected.add(item);
                                    map.put(position, true);
                                    break;

                                case R.id.check_present:
                                    item = (Items) holderName.checkPresent
                                            .getTag();
                                    presentSelected.add(item);
                                    map.put(position, true);
                                    break;

                                default:
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        });

                /*
                 * holderName.checkAbsent .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new
                 * CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                 * 
                 * @Override public void onCheckedChanged( CompoundButton
                 * buttonView, boolean isChecked) { // TODO Auto-generated
                 * method stub holderName.checkAbsent.setSelected(isChecked); //
                 * selected1.add();
                 * 
                 * } });
                 * 
                 * holderName.checkPresent .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new
                 * CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                 * 
                 * @Override public void onCheckedChanged( CompoundButton
                 * buttonView, boolean isChecked) { // TODO Auto-generated
                 * method stub holderName.checkAbsent.setSelected(isChecked); //
                 * selected2.add();
                 * 
                 * } });
                 */
                convertView.setTag(holderName);

            } else {
                holderName = (ViewHolderName) convertView.getTag();
            }

            if (holderName.name != null)
                holderName.name.setText(ei.getName());
            convertView.setOnCreateContextMenuListener(null);
        }
        return convertView;
    }

    public static class ViewHolderName {
        public TextView name;
        public RadioGroup radioGroup;
        public RadioButton checkPresent;
        public RadioButton checkAbsent;
    }

    public static class ViewHolderSectionName {
        public TextView section;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should maintain/preserve the state of 'checked' radiobutton, to keep it checked on scrolling up and down, because on scrolling list view up/down, every list-item/view is re-created by the list adapter.

You should preserve the position/index of checked radio button by setting listener on radio button.

You can use hashMap to hold list-item as s KEY and 'Checked' status as a value. 
When user check mark the box, add key value to map and When user uncheck the box than remove key from map.

Use this map in rendering list view. Code is as below :

```
private Map<Integer, Boolean> map =  new HashMap<Integer, Boolean>();    

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

     Boolean present = map.get(position);
     if(present != null && present.booleanValue()){
       // set present checkbox selected
     } else {
       // set absent checkbox selected
     }

    holderName.radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
       public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
               switch (checkedId) {
                   case R.id.check_absent:
                        map.put(position, false)
                        break;
                   case R.id.check_present:
                        map.put(position, true)
                        break;
               }
      }
   });
}
```

Comment: Let me know if you cant get my point, so i can post the code for you

Comment: yes @Rakesh Bhalani i got your point.. let me try once if i don't find solution then i will ask for your help.. and thanks for hint of the solution...

Comment: I used your code but i am unable to resolved that issue.. it is not working for me. please help me.. i am trying my best to resolve it from yesterday....

Comment: @RakeshBhalani.. i have updated the code. please have a look.. else i can do one thing i can mail you the code so that you can run it and get to know where i am doing wrong. Thanks for reply and help

Comment: You are puting 'true' for both present & absent in switch case in listener, please put 'false' for absent & true for present in map.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25677/discussion-between-mahaveer-muttha-and-rakesh-bhalani)